# Android Studio on Ubuntu - transparent screens bug

Tags: android, android-studio, ubuntu-14.04

I'm using Android Studio on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, sometimes i have this problem. Anyoune know how can i fix this?

[image]

Comment: Are you using openjdk or oraclejdk ?

Comment: Im using oraclejdk

Comment: Its a #bug . use 15.04

Answer (score 2):

Often such problems are detected by Android Studio and the solution for these problems are mentioned in **Event Log.** The log should detect the problem upon startup.

[This](http://www.webupd8.org/2009/08/fix-application-transparent-bug-in.html) document should fix your problem, as it is a common bug for Ubuntu users.

Answer (score 1):

It is my problem too,i found that this is [Ubuntu bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/compiz/+bug/1072206) (they say related to nVidia driver but i experience it with AMD Radeon too)!

However you can **kill compiz process** in System-Monitor or **dismiss dialog and show it again**.